Next.js not rendering MDX components
I'm trying to render a mdx file on my NEXTJS portfolio website for a blog of sorts. I'm able to get the text of the mdx file onto my site, but for some reason my site won't render the mdx file properly, things like headers or code segments show up the same as text. 
This is how it should look

This is how it actually renders
This is the code I'm using to render the mdx file. I've been using this repo as a guide
Page.tsx
import {FC} from 'react'
import {allDocs} from "contentlayer/generated"
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation'
import Navbar from '@/app/components/navbar'
import { MDXProvider } from '@mdx-js/react'
import "@/app/styles/mdx.css"
import { Mdx } from '@/app/components/mdx-components'


interface PageProps { 
  params: {
    slug: string
  }
}

async function getDocFromParams(slug: string) {
  const doc = allDocs.find((doc) => doc.slugAsParams === slug)

  console.log("slug: ", slug)

  if (!doc) notFound()

  return doc
}

const page = async ({params}: PageProps) => {
  const doc = getDocFromParams(params.slug)

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <div className='mx-96'>
        <h1 className='text-[40px] font-bold'>{(await doc).title}</h1>
        <div className='flex mb-[40px]'>
          <h2 className='text-[15px] font-semibold text-subMono'>{(await doc).datePublished} &ensp; {(await doc).readTime}</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <Mdx code={(await doc).body.code}/>
        </div>
        <p>{(await doc).body.code}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default page

mdx-component.tsx
import * as React from "react"
import Image from "next/image"
import { useMDXComponent } from "next-contentlayer/hooks"

import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import { Callout } from "@/components/callout"
import { MdxCard } from "@/components/mdx-card"

const components = {
  h1: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <h1
      className={cn(
        "mt-2 scroll-m-20 text-4xl font-bold tracking-tight",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  h2: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <h2
      className={cn(
        "mt-10 scroll-m-20 border-b pb-1 text-3xl font-semibold tracking-tight first:mt-0",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  h3: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <h3
      className={cn(
        "mt-8 scroll-m-20 text-2xl font-semibold tracking-tight",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  h4: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <h4
      className={cn(
        "mt-8 scroll-m-20 text-xl font-semibold tracking-tight",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  h5: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <h5
      className={cn(
        "mt-8 scroll-m-20 text-lg font-semibold tracking-tight",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  h6: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <h6
      className={cn(
        "mt-8 scroll-m-20 text-base font-semibold tracking-tight",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  a: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <a
      className={cn("font-medium underline underline-offset-4", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  p: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <p
      className={cn("leading-7 [&:not(:first-child)]:mt-6", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  ul: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <ul className={cn("my-6 ml-6 list-disc", className)} {...props} />
  ),
  ol: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <ol className={cn("my-6 ml-6 list-decimal", className)} {...props} />
  ),
  li: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <li className={cn("mt-2", className)} {...props} />
  ),
  blockquote: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <blockquote
      className={cn(
        "mt-6 border-l-2 pl-6 italic [&>*]:text-muted-foreground",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  img: ({
    className,
    alt,
    ...props
  }: React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>) => (
    // eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-img-element
    <img className={cn("rounded-md border", className)} alt={alt} {...props} />
  ),
  hr: ({ ...props }) => <hr className="my-4 md:my-8" {...props} />,
  table: ({ className, ...props }: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableElement>) => (
    <div className="my-6 w-full overflow-y-auto">
      <table className={cn("w-full", className)} {...props} />
    </div>
  ),
  tr: ({ className, ...props }: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLTableRowElement>) => (
    <tr
      className={cn("m-0 border-t p-0 even:bg-muted", className)}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  th: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <th
      className={cn(
        "border px-4 py-2 text-left font-bold [&[align=center]]:text-center [&[align=right]]:text-right",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  td: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <td
      className={cn(
        "border px-4 py-2 text-left [&[align=center]]:text-center [&[align=right]]:text-right",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  pre: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <pre
      className={cn(
        "mb-4 mt-6 overflow-x-auto rounded-lg border bg-black py-4",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  code: ({ className, ...props }) => (
    <code
      className={cn(
        "relative rounded border px-[0.3rem] py-[0.2rem] font-mono text-sm",
        className
      )}
      {...props}
    />
  ),
  Image,
  Callout,
  Card: MdxCard,
}

interface MdxProps {
  code: string
}

export function Mdx({ code }: MdxProps) {
  const Component = useMDXComponent(code)

  return (
    <div className="mdx">
      <Component components={components} />
    </div>
  )
}

